# ¿Cómo colocar cajas del mismo tamaño? Tengo un problema

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Buenas, estoy creando una página web en html y css, pero me topé con un problema:

Resulta que en la sección de trabajos quiero que todas las cajas tengan el mismo tamaño, y por alguna razón las cajas de la derecha del todo se recortan y quedan más pequeñas que el resto.

Pensé que podría ser por el `visibility: hidden`, pero lo modifiqué y de igual forma no he logrado arreglarlo, aquí les coloco el código que he hecho para ver si pueden ayudarme:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: "OpenSans-Regular", sans-serif;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.foto img {
 width: 115px;
}
.contenedor {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* ---------- HEADER ---------- */
header {
 background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/196700/pexels-photo-196700.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb") #a49150;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 max-height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}
header .menu {
 margin: 40px 0;
 text-align: right;
}
header .menu a {
 margin: 0 20px;
 color: #fff;
 padding-bottom: 9px;
 font-size: 1em;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
header .menu a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
header .contenedorTexto {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 margin: 190px 0;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto {
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 60px;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto h1,
header .contenedorTexto .texto h2 {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Light";
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto .nombre {
 font-family: "OpenSans-Bold";
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto .profesion {
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
}
/* ---------- MAIN ---------- */
.main .acercaDe .contenedor {
 overflow: visible;
}
.main .acercaDe {
 text-align: center;
}
.main .acercaDe .foto { 
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.main .acercaDe .foto img {  
 vertical-align: top;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
}
.main .acercaDe .texto {
 color: #5a5a5a;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.main .acercaDe .texto .titulo {
 font-size: 1.9em;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 color: #dd820d;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 34px;
}
.main .acercaDe .texto .bold {
 color: #3895ea;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.main .trabajos {
 background: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 60px 0;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.main .trabajos .titulo {
 font-size: 1.9em;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 color: #323068;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 34px;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background: grey;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo {
 width: 23%;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .thumb {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .thumb img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 450px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .descripcion {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <nav class="menu">
    <a href="#">Acerca de</a>
    <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
   </nav>
   <div class="contenedorTexto">
    <div class="texto">
     <h1 class="nombre">Anaís Mora</h1>
     <h2 class="profesion">Fotógrafa profesional</h2>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </header>
 <section class="main">
  <section class="acercaDe">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <figure class="foto">
     <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/56.jpg" alt="Anaís Mora">
    </figure>
    <div class="texto">
     <h3 class="titulo">Acerca de</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="bold">consectetur adipisicing elit</span>. Eum animi totam nam delectus optio quas sequi. Omnis fuga amet quae ipsum. Laboriosam veniam labore <span class="bold">praesentium totam</span>, quos incidunt iste autem.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="trabajos">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <h3 class="titulo">Trabajos</h3>
    <div class="contenedor-trabajos">
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <section class="contacto">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <h3 class="titulo">Contacto</h3>
    <form action="" class="formulario">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre:" name="nombre" required>
     <input type="email" placeholder="Correo:" name="correo" required>
     <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje:"></textarea>
     <input class="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="redesSociales">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
    <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
   </div>
  </section>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La etiqueta figure por defecto tiene unos estilos predefinidos, y en este caso lo que te esta molestando es su margen. Con poner margin: 0, sería suficiente.
Echa un vistazo a este artículo que creo podría resultarte interesante:

http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/por-que-nunca-usar-reset.css-sino-normalize.css-c113822l/

La definición bastante básica de que son reset.css y [normalize-css](/questions/tagged/normalize-css) sería la siguiente:

**reset.css** se creo con la intención de anular todos o casi todos (según las necesidades) los estilos por defecto de las etiquetas html, ya que por desgracia cada navegador aplica estilos diferentes en dichas etiquetas y sin usar reset.css era muy difícil conseguir se viera una web exactamente igual en los distintos navegadores.
Pero esto nos añadía el trabajo extra de crear los estilos básicos que necesitaramos de nuevo, como por ejemplo los estilos de los enlaces....

**normalize.css**

> "Normalize es un fichero CSS que apenas ocupa 8 KB,  cuyo principal
> objetivo es mantener los estilos similares en los navegadores, ya que
> cada uno agrega sus propios estilos por defecto, por ejemplo te suelen
> agregar distintos paddings, margins, font-sizes,etc. Con Normalize CSS
> lo que hacemos es regularizarlos y que nuestra web se vea igual
> independientemente del navegador donde se visualice. Además está
> preparado para adaptarse completamente a HTML5."

**La definición anterior ha sido copiada de la página de Falcon Master de su artículo "Que es Normalize CSS – Reseteando los estilos del navegador"- http://www.falconmasters.com/recursos-herramientas/normalize-css/**

Con normalize.css no tenemos que volver a escribir los estilos básicos, ya que los mantiene pero los iguala en los diferentes navegadores.

Comment: Me gustó tu enlace, es muy útil. Si pusieras un resumen en tu respuesta explicando para qué sirve normalize.css ya sería perfecta.

Comment: Buenas @Awes0meM4n, gracias por comentármelo, acabo de editar la respuesta y he ampliado la información que podía crear más dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien el problema, consiste en que la cuarta imagen (flor) de la derecha está "desfasada" en la sección trabajos.

Lo que veo es que dichas imágenes tienen una margen en la etiqueta `<figure>` que las "desplaza" a la derecha.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: "OpenSans-Regular", sans-serif;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.foto img {
 width: 115px;
}
.contenedor {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* ---------- HEADER ---------- */
header {
 background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/196700/pexels-photo-196700.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb") #a49150;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 max-height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}
header .menu {
 margin: 40px 0;
 text-align: right;
}
header .menu a {
 margin: 0 20px;
 color: #fff;
 padding-bottom: 9px;
 font-size: 1em;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
header .menu a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
header .contenedorTexto {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 margin: 190px 0;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto {
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 60px;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto h1,
header .contenedorTexto .texto h2 {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Light";
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto .nombre {
 font-family: "OpenSans-Bold";
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
}
header .contenedorTexto .texto .profesion {
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
}
/* ---------- MAIN ---------- */
.main .acercaDe .contenedor {
 overflow: visible;
}
.main .acercaDe {
 text-align: center;
}
.main .acercaDe .foto { 
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.main .acercaDe .foto img {  
 vertical-align: top;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
}
.main .acercaDe .texto {
 color: #5a5a5a;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.main .acercaDe .texto .titulo {
 font-size: 1.9em;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 color: #dd820d;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 34px;
}
.main .acercaDe .texto .bold {
 color: #3895ea;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.main .trabajos {
 background: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 60px 0;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.main .trabajos .titulo {
 font-size: 1.9em;
 font-family: "OpenSans-Semibold";
 color: #323068;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 34px;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background: grey;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo {
 width: 23%;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .thumb {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .thumb img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 450px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.main .trabajos .contenedor-trabajos .trabajo .descripcion {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <nav class="menu">
    <a href="#">Acerca de</a>
    <a href="#">Trabajos</a>
    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
   </nav>
   <div class="contenedorTexto">
    <div class="texto">
     <h1 class="nombre">Anaís Mora</h1>
     <h2 class="profesion">Fotógrafa profesional</h2>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </header>
 <section class="main">
  <section class="acercaDe">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <figure class="foto">
     <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/56.jpg" alt="Anaís Mora">
    </figure>
    <div class="texto">
     <h3 class="titulo">Acerca de</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="bold">consectetur adipisicing elit</span>. Eum animi totam nam delectus optio quas sequi. Omnis fuga amet quae ipsum. Laboriosam veniam labore <span class="bold">praesentium totam</span>, quos incidunt iste autem.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="trabajos">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <h3 class="titulo">Trabajos</h3>
    <div class="contenedor-trabajos">
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="trabajo">
      <figure class="thumb">
       <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/macro-cuadrada-de-la-flor-de-la-maravilla-del-gerbera-31590353.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum">
      </figure>
      <div class="descripcion">
       <p class="nombre">Lorem Ipsum</p>
       <p class="categoria">HTML - CSS - PHP</p>
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <section class="contacto">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <h3 class="titulo">Contacto</h3>
    <form action="" class="formulario">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre:" name="nombre" required>
     <input type="email" placeholder="Correo:" name="correo" required>
     <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje:"></textarea>
     <input class="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="redesSociales">
   <div class="contenedor">
    <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
    <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
   </div>
  </section>
 </footer>
</body>
```